# Debugging return statement within catch block

Tags: java, exception

I'm developing an android application where I use the following snippet:

```
private Boolean myMethod(boolean isOnline) {
    try {
        if (isOnline) {
            ...
            return true;    
        } 
        else {
            ...
            return true;
        }
    } 
    catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        this.e = e;
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        this.e = e;
        return false;
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        this.e = e;
        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        this.e = e;
        return false;
    }
}
```

while I'm debugging the code. The return statement in the last catch block `return false;` is executed without executing `this.e = e;` and `this.e` is `null`. If I remove the last catch block

```
catch (Exception e) { 
    this.e = e;
    return false;
}
```

then the return statement in the following catch block is executed

```
catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
    this.e = e;
    return false;
}
```

What mistakes did I make?

Comment: which exception is called when you execute this code

Comment: Catching a `Exception` is generally a bad idea as you might be catching some `Exception` that doesn't correspond to you, so you should always catch just the specific exceptions you know your `try` block could throw. That's probably what's happening here, you're entering `Exception` because it's more generic than the `XmlPullParserException`.

Comment: What do you want to achieve??

Comment: u mean to say when u catch Exception, this.e is still null??

Comment: @ Amith GC . Exactly ,you're correct . What should I need to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is adding this block:

```
catch (Exception e) { 
    this.e = e;
    return false;
}
```

It will catch everything, leading to your XmlPullParserException not being called IMO.

Comment: Really?? Implemented code should call XmlPullParserException if code throws XmlPullParserException because Exception hass been added at last.

Comment: A small code test I tried that throws `NullPointerException` and catches `NullPointerException` and `Exception` doesn't really agree with your answer though.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the feedback. I guess I was wrong.

Comment: But exception is null :-(

Comment: @RakeshL, thats a pretty weird case. Unless we see all the relevant code, we will be just guessing. By the way what do you want this.e for?